# Soap WebService with Database access

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services, asmx

So basically I have a Soap webservice that does inserts and retrieves some data from a SqlServer database.

The webservice uses a Singleton that is responsible for the DB stuff.

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private DBAccess dbaccess;
    public Service()
    {
        dbaccess = DBAccessLocalhost.GetInstance();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Profile> XXX(Guid a, uint b, DateTime c)
    {
        return dbaccess.XXX(a, b, c);
    }
    ...
}
```

The singleton that access the database. It has allot of methods that basically do this.

```
public class DBAccessLocalhost : DBAccess
{
    private static DBAccess instance = null;
    private string connectionString;

    public static DBAccess GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DBAccessLocalhost();

        return instance;
    }

    private DBAccessLocalhost()
    {
        connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=2000;Pooling=false";
    }

    public override void XXX(Guid a, uint b, DateTime c)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        string strSql = "SP_Name";
        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", (int)b);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read() && dr.HasRows)
            {
                //Do stuff...
            }

            dr.Close();

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new DBError("Errors: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
     }
```

Second version:

```
public class DBAccessLocalhost : DBAccess
{
    private static DBAccess instance = null;
    private string connectionString;

    public static DBAccess GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DBAccessLocalhost();

        return instance;
    }

    private DBAccessLocalhost()
    {
        connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=2000;Pooling=true";
    }

    public override void XXX(Guid a, uint b, DateTime c)
    {
        string strSql = "SP_Name";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", (int)b);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            //....
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new DBError("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that sometimes I get this exception:

```
 DBAccessWebSerice,System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Server was unable to process 
 request. ---> Errors: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available    
 Connection. The connection's current state is closed (Sometimes says connecting).

 Server stack trace: 
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime 
 operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, 
 ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage  
 methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

The problem may be because there are to many connections at the same time to the database?

Probably this isn't the best way do to this. But if you have a better way of doing this or have a solution for this problem, please say.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Also, always include the original exception when throwing a new exception: `throw new DBException(message, ex);`

Answer (score 2):

Singleton is not a good pattern for Db Access. Use static methods for retrieving data. Most likely, your problem is that 2 threads accessed your instance and you have no lock to prevent it.
Other points:

1. don't name your stored procedures with "SP_" prefix
2. use `using` while dealing with disposable objects such as datareader
3. Use connection pooling

I see potential for all sorts of issues in the code you presented here. For example, if reading datareader errors out, you will not clean resources.

This is one way:

```
public override void XXX(Guid a, uint b, DateTime c)
{
    string strSql = "SP_Name";
    lock (lockObject) {  // lock the code for the duration of execution so it is thread safe now (because you in singleton) 
// But this is bad for DB access !!!! What if SP executes long - other threads have to wait
// Use simple static methods for data access and no `lock`
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", (int)b);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
                // no need for any `try-catch` here because `using` is that and `finally`
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        //....
                    }
                }

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Other option, if you want to have better control of exception handling is to use `try-catch-finally` instead of `using`. Then, in finally, you will do another `try-catch` to clean-up down your resources.
   //Pseudocode

```
try
       connection
       command
       datareader
   catch (Exception ex)
       prepare user message
       log or
       throw/throw new, etc // depends. This is Webservice, may be log and response with error message
   finally
       try
          if datareader alive
             close datareader 
             dispose datareader 
       catch // do nothing here
       try
          if command alive
             dispose command
       catch // do nothing here
       try
          if connection alive
             close connection 
             dispose connection 
       catch // do nothing here
```

Comment: Regarding point 1, the name "SP_" was just as an example ;) I've added a second version with some changes that I think it was what you were talking about. If this is not the proper way, please point me some example or something like that.

Comment: Look my edits. If you insist on singleton with instance method - add `lock{}`. Or, better, make your method `static` and no `lock`. What I mean is, move code from `XXX` to `private static void execXXX` and call that from `XXX`

Comment: In a web service, you'll need a lock around the creation of the singleton instance in any case because of multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach, abandoning the singleton idea as the other answer suggests:

- Pass a Func into your service which is the factory for data access object
- Have DBAccess implement IDisposable which and use a using block

  ```
  public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {
     private Func<DBAccess> getDBAccess;

     public Service(Func<DBAccess> getDBAccess)
     {
        this.getDBAccess = getDBAccess;
     }

     [WebMethod]
     public List<Profile> XXX(Guid a, uint b, DateTime c)
     {
          using(var dbaccess = this.getDBAccess())
          {
              return dbaccess.XXX(a, b, c);
          }  
     }
     ...
   }
  ```